# Why do symmetric monoidal structures have such a confusing name?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, monoid

I've been reading Spivak and Fong's "An invitation to applied category theory" and I read that a *monoid* is a function $*$, called *monoid multiplication* for which:

- There is a specific element $I$ in the function domain, called *monoidal unit*, for which *unitality* holds
- The operation is associative (i.e. $*(*(a,b),c) = *(a, *(b, c))$ for all $a,b,c$ in the domain

I also read that a monoid can support commutativity.
Then, there are *symmetric monoidal preorders* which, to my understanding, are commutative (aka **symmetric**) monoids in which the function domain is a preorder, and an extra property (monotonicity) holds.

My doubt is, don't the terms *symmetric monoidal* and *commutative monoid* mean the same thing, when they're clearly not? To be precise, the former doesn't mention in any way the monotonicity, almost as if it were implied that having a *commutative monoid* in which the domain is a preorder **grants** monotonicity, but this clearly isn't the case.
Is there an explanation for this unfortunate naming?

Comment: A monoid is not a function, but a set equipped with a function taking two arguments, and the rest of the question is... just very unclear. A symmetric monoidal preorder is, as you say, a set $P$ equipped with a preorder relation $\le$, and a monoid operation $\ast$ which is commutative and monotonic (wrt the product order on the domain). Now the terms symmetric monoidal and commutative monoid do not, in general, mean the same thing --it happens to be so for posets.